# Force app to load data via WiFi

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I have a device that can be reached by connecting to its wifi network and browsing to 192.168.1.1.
The wifimanager in android will show that i'm connected to the network but it's showing that I don't have internet access (which is normal in this case).
This causes an issue when GPRS is activated because the webview in my application is trying to load 192.168.1.1 via the GPRS-connection since this connection has internet access.
In which way can I force a webview in my app to load an url via WiFi instead of GPRS?

Comment: Probably not helpful but does http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#requestRouteToHost(int,%20int) do anything? (I'm new so maybe thats wrong)